# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted,Django Post Request

Tags: python, django

I'm getting an error while updating database records in django 1.8

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

my url:

`url(r'^blog/update/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$','news.views.update')`

```
def edit(request,id):
    blogs = Blog.objects.get(pk=id)

    return render_to_response('news/edit.html',{'blogs':blogs})

def update(request,id):
    if request.method=='POST':
        blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=id)
        blog.title = request.POST.get('title')
        blog.content = request.POST.get('content')
        blog.save()
        return HttpResponse('updated successfully!!')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('error')
```

news/edit.html

```
<form action="/blog/update/{{blogs.id}}/" method="POST">{%csrf_token%}
    <label>Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{blogs.title}}"><br>
    <label>Content:</label>
    <textarea cols="45" rows="4" name="content">{{blogs.content}}</textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: do u have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'  in your middlewares ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the csrf middleware to your `settings.py` file:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
...
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)
```

also, change

`return render_to_response('news/edit.html',{'blogs':blogs})`

to

`return render(request, 'news/edit.html', {'blogs': blogs})`

OR

`return render_to_response('news/edit.html', {'blogs': blogs},
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

This is because you need to add a context to each request.

[Similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547639/django-csrf-verification-failed)

Comment: Maybe the context isn't included properly... try changing `return render_to_response('news/edit.html',{'blogs':blogs})` to `return render(request, 'news/edit.html', {'blogs': blogs})`