# CSRF verification failed in django

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I am trying to finish a [geo Django tutorial](http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/geodjango-googlemaps-build.html) which is quite old (1.3). Till now I was doing great but I am stucked with a specific error.

I am trying to build the functionality in which I save some data to the table in db. 
This is my view:

```
# Import django modules
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import HttpResponse
import simplejson
from waypoints.models import Waypoint

def save(request):
'Save waypoints'
for waypointString in request.POST.get('waypointsPayload', '').splitlines():
    waypointID, waypointX, waypointY = waypointString.split()
    waypoint = Waypoint.objects.get(id=int(waypointID))
    waypoint.geometry.set_x(float(waypointX))
    waypoint.geometry.set_y(float(waypointY))
    waypoint.save()
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dict(isOk=1)),    mimetype='application/json')
```

When I select the Save button I get an error (in firebug):403 Forbidden
Now I know that is related with:

```
<h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
<p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>
```

But I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Either add `{% csrf_token %}` after your HTML `<form>` tag (safe) or add @csrf_exempt before `def save(request):` (unsafe)

Comment: @Selcuk thank you very much for the answer. Can you please be a bit more specific. Right now I don't have any form tag. Just: <input id=saveWaypoints type=button value=Save disabled=disabled> Should I add it insed the input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - CSRF verification failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547639/django-csrf-verification-failed)

Comment: How do you POST without a form tag? Through Javascript?

Comment: Yes. Using jquery. Its just a tutorial which I try to finish so I get a first idea of geodjango!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Selcuk suggested, using the `Django` decorator `csrf_exempt` on your view function should fix this. However, take into consideration that it won't protect your request against `CSRF` attacks.
You can read more about how it works [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works).

```
# Import django modules
from django.http import HttpResponse
# import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
# Import system modules
import simplejson
# Import custom modules
from googlemaps.waypoints.models import Waypoint

@csrf_exempt 
def save(request):
    'Save waypoints'
    for waypointString in request.POST.get('waypointsPayload', '').splitlines():
        waypointID, waypointX, waypointY = waypointString.split()
        waypoint = Waypoint.objects.get(id=int(waypointID))
        waypoint.geometry.set_x(float(waypointX))
        waypoint.geometry.set_y(float(waypointY))
        waypoint.save()
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dict(isOk=1)), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: Don't use this unless you have a very good reason. CSRF is a security measure that is there to avoid other people being able to post data on your behalf. See my answer for the secure solution.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to solve this is to add a {% csrf_token %} to your Django template. You need a form tag for this to work, and you should have one no matter what. Otherwise, how does the browser know where to send your data?

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id=saveWaypoints type=button value=Save disabled=disabled>
</form
```

The Django documentation has lots of good information on how CSRF works and why it's important:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it