# CSRF Cookie error with Chrome browser that I cannot solve

Tags: django, google-chrome, csrf

I'm using javascript with a Django api to submit a modal form.

I'm sending a CSRF cookie that works in other circumstances (like on other browsers or with other forms in Chrome), but when I submit a Django form, but it fails on chrome and I get the following error:

```
Error:
Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed.
Request aborted.
Reason given for failure: CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

I know for a fact that I'm sending the CSRF cookie, as I can see it in the inspect element.

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=*sometoken*
```

How might I fix this and what other information do you need?

Comment: I think this can help you [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547639/django-csrf-verification-failed)